# How to represent "1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>" by RegExp

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a string contain arr_key[key] by arr_value[key] with `RegExp` method. In this case `1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>` by `<ruby>1日<rp>(</rp><rt>ついたち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>` etc..

I try with `RegExp`: `/1<ruby>日<rp>\(<\/rp><rt>にち<\/rt><rp>\)<\/rp><\/ruby>/g` but it works not exactly. It also replaces something like `2<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>`

```
var my_string ="1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>abc";
function repair_input(rec){
    var arr_key ={
        key1:"1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
        key2:"2<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
        key3:"3<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",

        };
    var arr_value={
        key1:"<ruby>1日<rp>(</rp><rt>ついたち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
        key2:"<ruby>2日<rp>(</rp><rt>ふつか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
        key3:"<ruby>3日<rp>(</rp><rt>みっか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
    }
    for (var key in arr_key) {
        var my_regex = arr_key[key];
        var my_value = arr_value[key];
        my_regex=my_regex.replace(/\//g,"\\/");
        my_regex=my_regex.replace(/\(/g,"\\(");
        my_regex=my_regex.replace(/\)/g,"\\)");
        my_regex = "/"+my_regex+"/g";
        console.log(my_regex);
        var rec =rec.replace(my_regex,my_value);
        }
    return rec;

};
```

This code doesn't work at step `var rec =rec.replace(my_regex,my_value);`.
But when I past result which are received from step `console.log(my_regex);` for my_regex in step `var rec =rec.replace(my_regex,my_value);`. It works not exactly. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: does your `my_string` have `abc` at end or it is typed by mistake ?

Comment: Using a regular expression sounds like a bad plan. Why can't you just parse it as HTML and use selectors?

Comment: my_string is input and unpredictable. arr_key[key] can appear one or more times at anywhere. And I wish to see output which will be replaced corresponding with arr_value[key].

Comment: @tadman Would you like to explain more by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use a single object for mapping key/values instead of using two different object, and then read value based on key from that object

```js
var my_string = "1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>abc";

function repair_input(rec) {
  rec = rec.match(/^.*<\/ruby>/i)
  rec = rec ? rec[0] : rec
  var repairObj = {
    "1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>":"<ruby>1日<rp>(</rp><rt>ついたち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
    "2<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>":"<ruby>2日<rp>(</rp><rt>ふつか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
    "3<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>":"<ruby>3日<rp>(</rp><rt>みっか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",

  };
  return repairObj[rec] ? repairObj[rec] : 'No matching value found'
};

console.log(repair_input(my_string))
console.log(repair_input('some random string'))
```

***Note:-*** Not sure if `abc` at end of `my_string` is part of your input or not, if it is not then you can exclude this part

```
  rec = rec.match(/^.*<\/ruby>/i)
  rec = rec ? rec[0] : rec
```

Use regex only when you can't do it with HTML parser or any such sort of standard thing which is meant for such tasks

---

***Update:-*** `( and )` are special character in regex, so you need to escape it to match, else it will be interpreted as `capturing group`

```js
var my_string = "1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>abc";

function repair_input(rec) {
  var repairObj = {
    "1<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>": "<ruby>1日<rp>(</rp><rt>ついたち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
    "2<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>": "<ruby>2日<rp>(</rp><rt>ふつか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",
    "3<ruby>日<rp>(</rp><rt>にち</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>": "<ruby>3日<rp>(</rp><rt>みっか</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>",

  };
  Object.keys(repairObj).forEach(reg=>{
    temp = reg.replace(/([)(])/g, '\\$1')
    let regex = new RegExp(temp, 'gi')
    rec = rec.replace(regex, repairObj[reg])
  })
  return rec
};

console.log(repair_input(my_string))
```

Comment: @Co.UQ always welcome, does it solved your problem ?

Comment: I wish I can use RegExp than using split().join()

Comment: This is exactly what i want. Want to hug and invite you for lunch if you were here. Than you so much.